# For loop and array splitting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

This is the current code I have inside a function. I'm trying to create a for loop in the first one, but I'm not entirely sure that I did it correctly because the array I attempted to make is returning an error.

I keep getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: thisWord.split is not a function

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, can someone help please?

```
var thisWord = words 
for (q = 0; q < words.length; q++) {
    // cast the string to all lowercase
    thisWord[q] = words[q].toLowerCase(); 
}

var thisArray = thisWord.split('');

thisArray.sort();
```

Comment: `thisWord` is an `instanceof Array`. `.split('')` is to split a String into an Array.

Comment: Is `words` an array or a string? Could you give an example?

Comment: Can you rather explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: words is a pre-existing array that has hundreds of words in it. I connected the words.js to my html page. The code i'm currently working with is in another js file for the same html page and is also linked to it. Sorry if that doesn't make sense, english is not my first language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While  [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) are immutable, and you could use [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) for a whole string, you can assign the value of `toLowerCase` to another or the same variable.

```js
var words = "Es war einmal ein Prinz, der hatte",
    thisWord = words.toLowerCase(), 
    thisArray = thisWord.split('');

thisArray.sort();
console.log(thisWord);
console.log(thisArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `words` is an array of strings, you should be doing this:

```js
var words = ["asAAAaad", "SSssbb", "asddASD"];
var newWords = words.map(function(word) {
  return word.toLowerCase();
});
console.log(newWords); // ["asaaaaad", "ssssbb", "asddasd"];
newWords.sort();
console.log(newWords); // ["asaaaaad", "asddasd", "ssssbb"];
```

If words is a spaced string

```
var words = "asAAAaad SSssbb asddASD";
var newWords = words.split(" ");
console.log(newWords); // ["asAAAaad", "SSssbb", "asddASD"]
newWords.sort();
console.log(newWords); // ["SSssbb", "asAAAaad", "asddASD"]
```